# How to add icon of device on unity launcher?

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, launcher

My HDD is separated on three parts, two of them are on nfts, and the only way to reach some of this parts is through trash icon on unity launcher to start Nautilus. Is it any way to put ntfs parts of the disk on the unity launcher?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add my favorite places as a quicklist in my home's icon in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity)

Answer (score 3):

I used this topic: [How to add my favorite places as a quicklist in my home's icon in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity) to add my 2 partions to my home folder launcher.
See the post marked with the green seal of approval and it should be fairly easy to add mounted discs (just change the Exec command and the one line with all the options in an array ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment, without editing .desktop files and gconf keys. you might want to right click the nautilus icon when you have opened that and add select Keep In Launcher for quick access to nautilus. Or you can browse your files through the files place

Comment: If you tell me how to edit and what to edit in this files, I'll be very grateful!