# How to add my favorite places as a quicklist in my home's icon in Unity?

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists

So I saw all that fancy quicklists in dash, and I'm wondering if I can do it with nautilus to add places as a quicklist, like Videos, Pictures, Downloads.. etc,

So as a start, I tried to modify `/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop` and added this but it didn't work:

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;

[Videos Shortcut Group]
Name=Videos
Exec=nautilus ~/Videos
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Comment: have to logged out and back in since making the change or at least unity --reset

Comment: I tried that of-course.

Comment: The reason it did not work is most likely because of the line `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;` which should either be removed or replaced with `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;` as per the accepted answer.

Comment: It is better to read this ↠ http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top (contain a lot of quick-lists )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## ubuntu 11.10

Copy 'Home Folder' launcher file to your home directory:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

Open the file for editing in gedit:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop
```

copy of mine below:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Name=Home Folder
Comment=Open your personal folder
TryExec=nautilus
Exec=nautilus --no-desktop
Icon=user-home
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents;Music;Pictures;Downloads
[Videos Shortcut Group]
Name=Videos
Exec=nautilus Videos
TargetEnvironment=Unity


[Documents Shortcut Group]
Name=Documents
Exec=nautilus Documents
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Music Shortcut Group]
Name=Music
Exec=nautilus Music
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Pictures Shortcut Group]
Name=Pictures
Exec=nautilus Pictures
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Downloads Shortcut Group]
Name=Downloads
Exec=nautilus Downloads
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

after you have logged out and back (or just restart unity by typing `unity` in a terminal in you will have folders as a quicklist for the home folder icon.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned above, though that was Not  the Op's issue, starting in 11.10, when copying a .desktop to another location you must remove or comment out the line - 
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity; 

Otherwise your launcher icon will only launch the app, not control it. A 2nd icon will show up that does that.

Comment: This is the problem I have.. I'm trying to rectify it.. I'll read on and try my luck, else return back here.

Comment: Yes.. I'm very happy.. Struggled for an Hour.. @doug Thank You.. Ur comment set me on the right track :D

Comment: This is what will happen http://youtu.be/oS52pYNFZ6I .. If that line is not removed.

Answer (score 6):

## Ubuntu 12.04

As of 12.04, it is no longer necessary to create a quicklist, as Nautilus automatically gets a list of your bookmarks and makes a dynamic quicklist.