# How to add a bookmark to the Home Folder icon in Unity?

Tags: unity, nautilus, home-directory, icons, quicklists

In question [How to add my favorite places as a quicklist in my home's icon in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity) there is an explanation of how to add my favourite places as a quicklist in the home icon in Unity (i.e. Videos, Documents, Music etc). This is useful but is there a way of adding a Nautilus bookmark that I have created to this list. I tried simply replicating the text for one of the groups by editing (`gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`), i.e.

```
[Downloads Shortcut Group]  
Name=MyBookmark  
Exec=nautilus MyBookmark  
OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

but this had no effect.

With thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts you need to do with the .desktop file:

1. Add the shortcut name to the `X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts` key, e.g.:

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents;...;MyBookmark
   ```
2. Add the piece you already posted, just make sure that the section title is of the form [**<Shortcut Name>** Shortcut Group]:

   ```
   [MyBookmark Shortcut Group]
   Name=MyBookmark
   Exec=nautilus MyBookmark
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```

Also, it's `TargetEnvironment` instead of `OnlyShowIn`.