# How to add my favorite places as a quicklist in my home's icon in Unity with other languages?

Tags: unity

This question is related to the following [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity), just adapted to use this solution for other languages.

I'm working with german as main language and it works for me with Videos and Downloads, but not for the "translated" folders like "Bilder" for pictures, "Dokumente" for Documents and "Musik" for music.

I'm not the fittest in Linux, can you please tell me what to change? Just replace every Music with Musik in nautilus-home.desktop?

thanks

---

**solved!**
I tried in a VM to change it like mentioned above and everything works fine!

Comment: Please answer your question with a proper answer and mark it as the solution. Otherwise, the question will still be treated as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

works exactly as in linked question, just change lines like
Exec=nautilus ~/Documents to Exec=nautilus ~/Dokumente
and so on
will work

logout-login to apply changes

Answer (score 0):

Same your favorites folders names..

Example in Turkish language:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ammfi.jpg

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents;Music;Pictures;Downloads
[Videos Shortcut Group]
Name=Videolar
Exec=nautilus Videolar
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Documents Shortcut Group]
Name=Belgeler
Exec=nautilus Belgeler
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Music Shortcut Group]
Name=Müzik
Exec=nautilus Müzik
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Pictures Shortcut Group]
Name=Resimler
Exec=nautilus Resimler
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Downloads Shortcut Group]
Name=İndirilenler   
Exec=nautilus İndirilenler
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```