# Why are there two icons in the Unity launcher for Nautilus?

Tags: unity, icons

Okay, so I installed Ubuntu 11.10.

The thing is, when I click the home folder icon in the launcher (Win + 1), the home folder opens and a new icon appears in the launcher.

I want the windows to be highlighted in the first icon only if you catch my drift (4th icon).

I thought if I could remove the first icon and then right-click on the other icon and keep it in the launcher, it may work - but then folders open and the icon remains blank without any indication that a window is open (looks same as first icon).

[image]

Also, the icons numbered from top to bottom exclude the dash icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a Linux programmer, and this answer contains modifying files out of your home folder. It works for me, but do it on your own risk.

This problem appears when you configure your Home icon to have a quicklist for your favourite places [the way it is described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/35526#35526).

The way to solve it, as written on the [Bug 842257](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/842257) page, is instead of creating a copy of /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop in ~/.local/share/applications and modifying this copy, rather modifying the original file. So the steps are:

1. Delete the copy, if there is any: ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop
2. Open a terminal and write:

   ```
   gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop
   ```
3. Add this text at the bottom of the file, save and close.

   ```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Videos;Documents;Music;Pictures;Downloads
   [Videos Shortcut Group]
   Name=Videos
   Exec=nautilus Videos
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Documents Shortcut Group]
   Name=Documents
   Exec=nautilus Documents
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Music Shortcut Group]
   Name=Music
   Exec=nautilus Music
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Pictures Shortcut Group]
   Name=Pictures
   Exec=nautilus Pictures
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   [Downloads Shortcut Group]
   Name=Downloads
   Exec=nautilus Downloads
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
4. Reboot. It should work now, only one icon, with the quicklist.

If it still doesn't work, you can try Alt+F2, then run

```
unity --reset-icons
```

This will reset the icons of the original install on your launchbar, so you will have to repopulate it the way you want.

For getting the original nautilus-home.desktop file back, you can reinstall Nautilus and have the default settings and files:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Comment: For my recently upgraded 16.0 Ubuntu without anything in ~/.local/share/applications just `unity --reset-icons` worked well without restarting or anything else

Answer (score 6):

According to the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/842257/comments/6), you just need to remove the following line from your custom Nautilus launcher (~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop):

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

I had this problem and removing that line and logging out and logging back in worked for me.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, I found this file in /usr/share/applications.

Comment: But, that didn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is a confirmed bug. [Bug 842257](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/842257)

It will be fixed at some point. There should only be one icon in the Launcher.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Make sure you don't have a custom `nautilus-home.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`. When I deleted that everything started working again.

I created one a while ago in 11.04, I guess something has changed in 11.10.

Comment: it removed my icon
can u tell me how to get it back?

Comment: @SarveshLad Just click the dash icon (the Ubuntu logo) and type in `nautilus`. Drag the `Home Folder` icon into the launcher. Alternatively, you can open the application and then right click on the icon in the launcher and select `Keep in launcher`.

Comment: i tried that and it did fix it but when i configured my icon to include my fav places.. it returned back to the existing situation

Answer (score 1):

Just unlock the file manager from Launcher. Then, open it again from the search icon typing nautilus. Finally, lock it to launcher.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The dash icon is not supposed to have a number since it would be redundant. The numbers are there so that you can activate an entry by pressing super+num. For instance, in your case, you would be able to launch and/or switch to Firefox by pressing super+2 and super+3 for the terminal. Launching the dash is done by a simple tap on super.

I have seen the bug you're referring to, but it was quite some time ago. Have you installed all upgrades? I've also seen that caused by an extension, but I don't remember which it was, but it may have been one to add quicklists. It should not be that way out of the box. Try opening a guest session and I'm sure that problem goes away. Would be nice if you confirmed that though.

Comment: jusy installed 11.10 yesterday and yes i upgraded it and my system is uptodate

i did the numbering so it can be easy to interpret

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have a custom `nautilus-home.desktop` file without this problem, as some other answers have mentioned. Another fix (mentioned here: [Opening home folder causes another file cabinet icon to appear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86879/opening-home-folder-causes-another-file-cabinet-icon-to-appear)) is to go to `gnome-tweak-tool` and set `Have file manager handle the desktop` to off.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a contradiction in the 'Home Folder' file
`/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop`

In the original file this line exists:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

while in quick list it is:

```
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

This is solved by changing (TargetEnvironment=Unity) to:

```
TargetEnvironment=GNOME;Unity;
```

worked for me.