# Opening home folder causes another file cabinet icon to appear

Tags: 11.10, unity, nautilus, gnome-tweak-tool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there two icons in the Unity launcher for Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65996/why-are-there-two-icons-in-the-unity-launcher-for-nautilus)

When I launch Home Folder from the Unity Dash, a Files window opens instead of opening itself (as default). Also Home Folder icon launching works only once. Normal behavior occurs when I set off **'Have file manager handle the desktop'** on gnome-tweak-tool.

[image: Graphical explanation]

The issue is, as you can see, that instead of opening a 'Home Folder' window, a Files window is opened (gray drawer). The Home Folder launcher works only once, even after closing the Files window.

Comment: The issue is, as you can see, that instead of opening a 'Home Folder' window, a Files window is opened (gray drawer). The Home Folder launcher works only once, even after closing the Files window.

Comment: Oh, ok ok. I rest corrected ;)