# gedit default directory and .desktop file

Tags: launcher, compiz, gedit, .desktop, paths

I have an icon for gedit in my launcher in Ubuntu 16.04. I had a problem with multiple icons in the launcher (see, e.g., [Why are there two icons in the Unity launcher for Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65996/why-are-there-two-icons-in-the-unity-launcher-for-nautilus)), which I solved by some random unlock from launcher-lock to launcher actions. Now I have a single icon that starts gedit.

However, when I click on this icon, gedit is started in `/`. This is visible in the embedded terminal and in the save location for new documents (as well as the location for 'open other documents' when a new document is in focus).

How can I change this location? I tried to edit `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.gedit.desktop` to read `Exec=cd ~;gedit %U` but that resulted in `compiz` being active for 10sec at 15% cpu and then terminating without starting gedit.

When I start gedit from the terminal in any directory the location is set to this directory.

I also have a `/usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop` file but it is not used. `dconf-editor` shows that the `org.gnome` file is used, and indeed making changes to this file (e.g., changing captions) is reflected in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gedit/+bug/194904 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=504067 suggest this is NOT possible

2 comments noteworthy:

> Gedit remembers the last folder where a document was saved, so I think this cannot be applied right now. Open the bug again if you think that the current behavior is not the one expected.
>
> Regarding the first issue, he is right. Right after installation, gedit suggest the `/home/$(USER)/` directory to save a file instead of `/home/$(USER)/Documents`. I think this should be changed (if it is actually not only a problem of Ubuntu).

- The initial save location (ie. user home) is hardcoded into gedit
- Gedit will remember a new save location and make that the default

Comment: In that case, why does gedit (on my system) pick `/` instead of the last location a file is saved (I never save anything directly on `/`)? Apparently gedit cannot write this setting properly, so where is this stored? Could it be corrupted?

Comment: I got the same problem, but it happens randomly. Sometimes, the default is home, otherwise, it is root `/`.