# Weird space on launcher after making a custom quicklist

Tags: 11.10, launcher, quicklists

after applying the settings in question [How to add my favorite places as a quicklist in my home's icon in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity), i get the unity launcher just ok, but when opening a nautilus windows, a blank icon appears.

See screenshot, just under skype icon...

Any advise?

thanks a lot!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well, removing the .desktop file from my user folder and editing teh file in /usr/share/applications seems to work. 

But why my userspace file gets this extrange behaiviour?

Thanks in advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answered by OP in a comment:*

> Well, removing the `.desktop` file from my user folder and editing the
>   file in `/usr/share/applications` seems to work.