# How to add windows partition to unity home icon launcer ?

Tags: 11.10, unity, launcher, quicklists

I already seen examples for adding favorite places on home icon launcher for Documents, Music, Pictures, Downloads and already added it.

Now I want to have also add Windows partition so that when I click it will mount and open in nautilus. I didn't find any example for this anwhere. Is it possible or not, if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get something good enough by adding it to your Nautilus (file explorer) bookmarks, by pressing `Ctrl+D` when you have the partition (directory) open. Then, you can hit `Meta+F` (meta is usually the windows key) and typing the name.

**edit** -- you could probably follow this user's post, [How to add my favorite places as a quicklist in my home's icon in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity) and use a different directory path. If you need to figure out what the path is,

- Select the folder (or Windows partition) in question.
- Open up the editor with the `.desktop` file from the linked post.
- Paste (Ctrl+Shift+V).
- Remove the "file://" prefix.

Comment: Is this the only way ?

Comment: @GauravPadia, see edit, sorry!

Comment: I followed your suggestion in edit section, but its not working. I selected windows partition and paste it but I am not getting anything prefixed with file:// instead I am getting /media/SOFTWARES where SOFTWARES is my windows drive label. SO this is what I added:
"[SOFTWARES Shortcut Group]
Name=SOFTWARES
Exec=nautilus /media/SOFTWARES
TargetEnvironment=Unity"

It will open my partition only if it is already mounted else nautilus is saying "Could not found /media/SOFTWARES"

Comment: @GauravPadia, okay, sorry I misunderstood. Can you make the partition mount by default? You can probably use something like the "Disk Utility" or gparted to mount it, then copy the mount parameters to `/etc/fstab`. You should be able to add the `user` flag to the `/etc/fstab` line for your Windows partition so you can mount it with the "mount /media/SOFTWARES" command. Then, you can just make the `.desktop` file "mount /media/SOFTWARES && nautilus ...`.

Comment: I want to do without mounting by default because I do not need windows partitions everytime. Do you know any single command that will mount partition and open in nautilus ? Thanks al lot for your help anyway.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's 1 or 2 commands, so long as you have them both in the `.desktop` file. Check out the `noauto` and `user` options for `/etc/fstab`. [ http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html ]. You could, for example, set up the partition in any partition manager, then add the noauto and user options to /etc/fstab. Shouldn't bee too much work.