# change the default starting directory of nautilus from unity bar

Tags: 11.10, unity, nautilus, 64-bit

Currently nautilus opens the home directory by default.

However the command `nautilus /path/to/a/directory` opens nautilus with the selected directory open.

How do I edit the unity bar Home folder icon to include path to the directory of my choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot system in classic

If you are opening nautilus from *Applications->System Tools->File Browser* just right click on the Applications menu select "Edit Menus" select System Tools in the configuration window then right click on File Browser select properties remove the %U from the command line and replace with a new start location ie: / ( then close all the windows (this sounds more complicated than it is sorry) if you are starting nautilus from some other launcher just do the last bit.

May be this will help

Have a look at the answer to [How to add my favorite places as a quicklist in my home's icon in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35024/how-to-add-my-favorite-places-as-a-quicklist-in-my-homes-icon-in-unity)

You can change the first Exec line to read `Exec=nautilus Documents` and it will open your Documents folder.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. The instructions in the link worked! However, ubuntu 11.10 does not have a classic mode to boot into (atleast not by default, gnome shell will have to be installed).